# Installing leviton ODS10 motion occupancy switch on 3 way switch

Tags: wiring, lighting, switch, multiway-switch

I'm trying to install a motion sensor occupancy switch on a 3 way switch. It can be used with sensors in 2 locations as shown in instructions below, but I want to use the regular switch at the other end that is already installed, and not a motion sensor. So motion sensor at one end, and regular 3 way switch at other end.

In the switch I am replacing, I have 4 wires (Hot, ground, and 2 travelers) and only 3 wires to connect from my motion sensor switch (black, blue, green) as shown in diagram . I am trying to figure out how to wire them, and if this is possible. Thanks! Let me know if any other information or pics would be helpful.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That motion sensor is not designed to be a true 3-way switch so it cannot be used the way you want.

If you study the second diagram, you’ll realize that it effectively is two single-pole switches in parallel. Either one turning on will turn on the light; both must turn off to turn off the light. If you wire one sensor with one normal switch and you turn on the normal switch, the sensor will not be able to turn off the light.

You need to return the sensor and get a different model that will function as a true 3-way switch.